# How to add Labels to Bootstrap dialog footer

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Need to add `bootstrap` label on footer of `bootstrap3-dialog`. according to [this tutorial](http://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/) can add only buttons in footer area.

```
BootstrapDialog.show({
    title: 'Default Title',
    message: 'Click buttons below.',
    buttons: [{label: 'Title 1'}, {label: 'Title 2'}]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can handle that with CSS if you are familiar with, the aim is it will always be a button but with a "label" style, something like this :

1. Add a css class for each 'label' you want :

`BootstrapDialog.show({
        title: 'Default Title',
        message: 'Click buttons below.',
        buttons: [{
            label: 'Title 1',
            cssClass: 'buttonAsLabel1'
        }, {
            label: 'Title 2',
            cssClass: 'buttonAsLabel2'
        }]
    });`

2. Declare the Css classes the same way as the related Bootstrap label

`.buttonAsLabel1 {..}
 .buttonAsLabel2 {..}`

should worked ^^

Answer (score 3):

If the footer doesn't have any buttons will remain hidden by default (with `style="display:none;"`) 
I managed to add any custom HTML to the footer like this:

```
BootstrapDialog.show({
  title: 'Default Title',
  message: 'Custom Footer',
  onshow: function(dialogRef) {
    dialogRef.getModalFooter()
      .css({display:'inline'})
      .find('.bootstrap-dialog-footer')
      .append('<span>Anything</span>');
   }
});
```

This is a very basic example, just expand the idea.