# Allow the user to select and copy bootstrap button label

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Want to let user to select and copy `bootstrap` button label. It should like a label. According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35377806/how-to-add-labels-to-bootstrap-dialog-footer) unable to use labels in Bootstrap dialog footer. How to do it?

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">sample@yahoo.com</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a UX perspective, I don't get why you would want to do that. I mean, a button is used for a call to action. When copying text, should the call to action happen or not? I think you better use a text element or paragraph for copying text.

There are however multiple ways to make text selectable in a button. Here is a quick example I made by putting a text field into the button.

https://jsfiddle.net/o8eze0d2/

You can disable the button action when selecting text by adding in the onclick of the button

```
if (event.target === this)
```

or by adding an onmousedown listener call on the text field that does a

```
event.stopPropagation();
```