# How will make the button text selectable?

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I applied these styles to a button. but it does not work

```
<button type="button" name="tucson-yes" aria-live="polite" tabindex="1">HOLDIT</button>

-webkit-user-select: text;
-moz-user-select: text;
-ms-user-select: text;
user-select: text;
```

Comment: Please draft the question in an elaborated way to understand your issue,, probably better if you can provide an example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allow the user to select and copy bootstrap button label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35380570/allow-the-user-to-select-and-copy-bootstrap-button-label)

Comment: Seems to work in Chrome under Windows 8.1... [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/hyur0d7k/).

Comment: we has able to access the css file only so we over write with the css. change the button element to look like normal text @Gowtham-Shiva

Comment: It does not work for me in Chrome Version 61.0.3163.100 Os: Windows 10 and safari also @mr-lister

Comment: we has able to access the css file only so we over write with the css. change the button element to look like normal text. For example we click the normal text in webpage it select the particular text.If we click the button it does not select the text. so we can change the button element to look like text element with the css. @Sagar Pudi

Comment: @KarthickKumar In my fiddle, I can select the text in the button both by double clicking it, or by dragging across it with the mouse. No differences between the browsers.

Comment: @Mr Lister If we normally double click the text thus the text is selected.For myself I double click or drag anything inside button element  is does not select the text.

Comment: I find solution for that using `pointer-events: none;` we will overcome that

Answer (score 7):

It seems work if you start selecting **from the text**. Test on win10 ChromeBeta 75.

```css
button {
  -webkit-user-select: text;
  -moz-user-select: text;
  -ms-user-select: text;
  user-select: text;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" name="tucson-yes" aria-live="polite" tabindex="1">HOLDIT</button>
```

See my gif:

[image]

Comment: This works!  `user-select: all;` also works.

Comment: This does not seem to work in Safari 15 (2022). The button text can't be selected.

Answer (score 0):

I find solution for that using

> **`pointer-events: none;`**

we will overcome that

Comment: Indeed, with this button text can be selected with Safari but the button will not emit any `click` events anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using tailwind css use `select-text` on the button element. This will allow the text to be selectable.

Here is the official link https://tailwindcss.com/docs/user-select

Answer (score -1):

Wrap the button text in a div.

`<button><div>button label</div><button>`
worked for me